# Array.map inside Array.map is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting an array of object returned from Database.I want to map that array and inside that i want to map another array.But i am getting some error. If anyone knows please help out with this problem.

```
displayMovies(){
    if(!this.state.body) return ( <h2> Loading.... </h2>)
    else{

        return this.state.body.map((data) => {
            return(
                <div key={data._id}>
                    <li> {data.name} </li>
                    <ul>
                        {
                            return data.map((cast) => {
                                return <li> cast.name </li>
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

[Data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRQ2g.png)

Comment: `return data.map((cast) => {` --> `data.map((cast) => {`

Comment: can you explain it little bit. @YuryTarabanko

Comment: You don't need another `return`. You are in the middle of another return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in any function inside nested loop so you do not  need to `return` any thing
Replace

```
 return data.map((cast) => {
```

to

```
data.map((cast) => {
```

and add apply `map` function on `cast` property of `data`

```
displayMovies(){
    if(!this.state.body) return ( <h2> Loading.... </h2>)
    else{

        return this.state.body.map((data) => {
            return(
                <div key={data._id}>
                    <li> {data.name} </li>
                    <ul>
                        {
                            data.cast.map((cast) => {
                                return <li> {cast.name} </li>
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that and its saying
data.map() is not a function

Comment: One more thing you are accessing {data.name} name in data so how could you use this as array?

Comment: I thing you are missing some property between data and map which should be a array  `data.'property'.map`

Comment: I just added the image of response, if that helps

Comment: I just updated my answer check now You are missing caste property before map like this `data.caste.map`

Comment: Sorry cast not caste!

Comment: @abankitbaid could you accept this answer If It is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first map function returns an Object. Objects don't have map function use a for in loop instead, inside the loop, check if the property is an object.
Replace second map with something like this :

```
for (const key in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof(object[key]=='object') {
    // do something with object[key].name 
  }
}
```