# How to map array inside mapped array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typeerror

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Transactions() {
  const [allDetails, setAllDetails] = useState();
  const userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bankDetails'));
  const transactons = JSON.parse(userDetails[0].transactions);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/transactTo')
    .then((res)=>{
      setAllDetails(res.data);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="account">
        <h1>Transactions</h1>
          {transactons.map((value, key1)=>{
            return(
              <div key={key1} className="transaction">
                <div>
                  {allDetails.map((user, key2)=>{
                    user.acc_no = parseInt(user.acc_no);
                    if(user.acc_no === value.to){
                      return <div key={key2}style={{'background':`url(/${user.image}.png)`}} className="userdp"></div>;
                    }
                  })}
                  {value.amount}||
                  {value.to || value.from}
                </div>  
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Transactions;
```

I'm trying to map an array inside a mapped array and the thing is the second map shows an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. As soon as I comment the second map of 6 lines and run the code, it runs and again if I remove the comments it again runs properly but doesn't runs in the first render.
Can anyone give a proper solution. I tried [Array.map inside Array.map is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590382/array-map-inside-array-map-is-not-working) but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the `map` being inside another `map`.

`allDetails` is `undefined` when the component is first rendered. Since `undefined` is not an array, you cannot call `map` on it.

You need to check for `allDetails` to be loaded, for example like so:

```
function Transactions() {
  const [allDetails, setAllDetails] = useState();
  const userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bankDetails'));
  const transactons = JSON.parse(userDetails[0].transactions);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/transactTo')
    .then((res)=>{
      setAllDetails(res.data);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="account">
        <h1>Transactions</h1>
          {transactons.map((value, key1)=>{
            return(
              <div key={key1} className="transaction">
                <div>
                  {allDetails && allDetails.map((user, key2)=>{
                    user.acc_no = parseInt(user.acc_no);
                    if(user.acc_no === value.to){
                      return <div key={key2}style={{'background':`url(/${user.image}.png)`}} className="userdp"></div>;
                    }
                  })}
                  {value.amount}||
                  {value.to || value.from}
                </div>  
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Transactions;
```

Comment: Yes that too helped but I dont understand how it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess here you missed `[]` inside `useState`. As `allDetails` is an array, we should assign it like array in hooks.
Try with
`const [allDetails, setAllDetails] = useState([]);`

Comment: That helped the problem !!! Thanks : )

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi welcome) you can accept and upvote the answer :)